# Android static vs nonstatic issue

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to call the following:

```
public static void startfile() {
    Log.i("File Works", "working2 ");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("sdcard/sdtext.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get an error that tells me that "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method openFileOutput(String, int) from the type ContextWrapper"

So I searched for that error and found [this site](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-fix-cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method).

I implemented this:

```
public static void startfile(Trackfile O) {
    Log.i("File Works", "working2 ");
    O.nonstatstartfile();
}

public void nonstatstartfile(){
    Log.i("File Works", "nonStat");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("sdcard/sdtext.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

When I call startfile from another class getting a Null pointer error.  What argument do I need to send to avoid the null pointer error?

Comment: So why do you need this method to be static, if you're calling a non-static method inside it?

Comment: Do you use it from another class?

Comment: yes I am calling from another class

Comment: Then...

 public void startfile() {
    Log.i("File Works", "working2 ");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("sdcard/sdtext.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

You could put this method in that class and make it nonstatic, and use it without problems, and if you need that method in main class, you can call it by object of that class...

Comment: Edit your answer to add the code, much easier to read :)

Comment: Sorry buddy, but I dont know how...

Comment: @markonato when I do this `    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trackview);
        Log.i("tracking class", "Tracking started");
        
        
        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startFile);
     //myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
     myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
       Trackfile.startfile();

      }
      });


       }'

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `context` from activity like below

```
public static void startfile(Context c) {
    Log.i("File Works", "working2 ");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput("sdcard/sdtext.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: … and use `startfile(this)` in your activity. (Activity extends Context). You should also use an absolute path for your file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void startfile() {
    Log.i("File Works", "working2 ");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("sdcard/sdtext.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Add this method to your class, and use it without problems. 
If you need it in main class, use it over object.